# How to redirect and mask URL with .htaccess file in this specific case?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, masking

Background:

We have a domain hosted at provider A (abc.com).

We have webspace hosted at provider B (xyz.de).

So both domains are on different hosts.

---

Situation:

- User navigates to URL abc.com
- User is redirected to index.html on xyz.de
- URL shown in browser: xyz.de/index.html

---

Aim:

URL shown in browser: abc.com/index.html

---

So far, I thought of the following solution:

- move content from xyz.de to a subfolder named /sub
- put .htaccess-file into root of xyz.de
- let .htaccess-file redirect to index.html in xyz.de/sub
- let .htaccess-file mask displayed URL path (show abc.com/index.html instead of xyz.de/sub/index.html

---

My questions:

a) Will this work?

b) How exactly should the .htaccess-file look?

c) Is there another, easier solution?

---

Thank you very much for your hints and tips in advance.

Comment: No, this won't work. You will need to use the proxy module available for the apache http server instead, _unless_ you can implement an actual logic (maybe a php script) on xyz.de instead of just a static html file. Reason why you approach won't work simply is that you cannot somehow "mask" a URL shown in a browser. You can only redirect or rewrite. The proxy based approach requires you to be able to actually use the domain on abc.com, for example by means of a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess").

Comment: Another, much easier approach would be to simply use DNS to achieve what you want: you change the A record of `abc.com` (or the C-Name) to point to `xyz.de`. That will work _if_ you can tell the http server at xyz.de to listen to requests to abc.com, so if you have access to the http server configuration.

Comment: Thanks very much. we have simply booked some webspace from provider A. Guess, that's a viable solution. Appreciated your help!